# Why I see the content of my localhost instead of accessing my created virtual host?

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04

I'm working on Ubuntu-14 and I want to access http://localhost:8086/myproject.net using http://myproject.dev

- I created a new folder under "*/var/www/*" named "*myproject.net*"
- I added this line to "/etc/hosts"

  `127.0.0.1  myproject.dev`
- I created "*myproject.dev.conf*" file under "*/etc/apache2/sites-available*" which contains:

  `<VirtualHost *:86>
  ServerAdmin i-put-my-email-here
  ServerName myproject.dev
  ServerAlias www.myproject.dev
  DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject.net/
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  </VirtualHost>`
- I enabled my site using

  `sudo a2ensite myproject.dev.conf`
- I restarted Apache

  `sudo service apache2 restart`
- I verified that Apache is running using

  `sudo service apache2 status`

Now when I tape http://myproject.dev:8086 I see the content of my *localhost* (like when I do http://localhost:8086) not the content of *myproject*!

Am I missing a step or Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `*:86` and `8086` have little in common...

Comment: @arkascha I installed Jenkins on my PC and it's working under http://127.0.0.1:8080 this is why I changed the port to 8086

Comment: Which is perfectly ok since it is your own choice. But still `86` and `8086` are two different numbers. Your `vhost` is defined on port `86`, the incoming request is on port `8086`. That does not match...

Comment: @arkascha Thank you I just changed `<VirtualHost *:86>` by `<VirtualHost *:8086>` in "/etc/apache2/sites-available/myproject.dev.conf" and it works!

Comment: @arkascha Can you please post your comment as an answer to mark it as resolved. So others having the same issue can view/use the solution?

Comment: Sure, makes sense. Glad I could be of help ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take care to define your virtual host on the correct address and port so that it can be matched for an incoming request. Otherwise the default host will be selected to respond to the request.

In your specific example you have to change the definition from

```
<VirtualHost *:86>
```

to use the port your http server is obviously listening on and that you make the request to:

```
<VirtualHost *:8086>
```

Oh, and... don't forget to restart your http server process after such a change ;-)